# python multiprocessing for loop example

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to optimize an image matching process,
where I have a big set of images and each image needs to be compared to all other images.
I want break the task between multiple processes, but I'm not sure how to apply the multiprocessing package for such cases.

To simplify the problem, how do I divide the next for loop between multiple processes?

```
def looploop(max_index):
    res = []
    for i in range(max_index):
        for j in range(i+1, max_index):
            res.append((i, j))
    return res
```

Comment: Is that honestly the for loop you're running, or a simplified example of something else?

Comment: look at `multiprocessing.Pool`

Comment: As stated in the question, this is a simplified example, and I'm asking how to use the multiprocessing package for it...

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code should help:

```
def run_in_parallel(funcs, **kwargs):
    proc = []
    for func, kw in funcs, kwargs:
        p = Process(target=func, kwargs=kwargs)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()
```

with this code you'll be able to run each iteration in a different process, or to split it however you want